# CSS General Formatting with Div Tags/Floating

Tags: css, html, positioning

I'm new to CSS and have a somewhat general question, but with a specific purpose.

Here is the webpage in question: http://www.lymemd.org/indexmm6.php

I have several DIVs: #BannerArea, #BannerinLeft, and #BannerinRight, all which format everything in the green square.  I'm looking to split everything up and so something like this:

[image: What I want layout to look like]

If anyone could help point me in the right direction in terms of what tags I'll need to do and what I'll need to get rid of, I would be very grateful.  I have tried many times to get everything right, but I always end up making something worse.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Please show us your HTML and CSS code that you have tried so far.

Comment: I simply made the #bannerinleft float to the left with a background, made the #bannerinright float to the right with a background, but found that the "support us" section, would push the "What's new" and "Diane Rehm" sections down with it, rather than pushing only the Diane Rehm section down.  Are you able to see the code by just looking at it in the active webpage?

Comment: Seems like you would benefit from some basic css/html tutorials and there are dozens of sites out there that can help with particular layout structures.

Comment: This is not a "basic" CSS fundamentals kind of thing. Please, produce a basic fiddle with CSS/HTML only and let me see how it works out

Comment: @Eric At StackOverflow you should not post links to your site and say "go here to see my site and delve through the code yourself". What if your site is carrying a virus? Instead, the FAQ suggest that you post your relevant code (in this case HTML and CSS) here using our built-in code detection and syntax highlighting. That way you've done the work of isolating the problem and we can help you as if we were at your desk looking over your shoulder. If a live example is necessary, use jsfiddle.net or codepen.io

Comment: Thanks for the advice, Tyler, I'll do that in the future.

Comment: @LOTUSMS what's not basic?

Comment: @Sam You can not simply create this without JQuery. Please show me. If you do anything like [THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/83ngD/6/) You'll find out that there is no fluidity at all. You'll have to manually re-adjust the size and positioning of everything when you add content. It is very rookie and sloppy way to develop. He shouldn't be learning the wrong way

Comment: @LOTUSMS You can change those height values to min-height values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to make two columns, the left one including the Twitter and What's New div, and the right one including the Support Us and Diane Rehm divs. These two columns will have to float, so make sure they are in a container of the correct width. The top div is easy.

Here's a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/83ngD/7/

The basic HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="topgreen"></div>
    <div id="leftcolumn">
        <div id="twitter"></div>
        <div id="whatsnew"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightcolumn">
        <div id="supportus"></div>
        <div id="dianerehm"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The basic CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 960px; /*/ example width /*/
    margin: 0 auto; /*/ centers the div /*/
}
#topgreen {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px; /*/ example height /*/
}
#leftcolumn {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
#rightcolumn {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
```

Now just fill the other divs with the content you want. The code above will give you the layout from your picture, but very basic.

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed answer.  I will try this during the afternoon and comment back here.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not going to work. I added text to your divs and they do not resize. There's no fluidity in this technique. See your updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/83ngD/6/)

Comment: No problem, hope you can figure it out! It'll probably be easiest to just rebuild the page and go from there. Create a new HTML document in your favorite editor and use the code from my jsfiddle as base. You'll learn a lot just from examining the current code. Also, get an extension like Firebug for your browser, it will tell you exactly what part of the code does what!

Comment: @LOTUSMS The heights that I gave to the divs in the fiddle were so that he would recognize the structure of the image he posted. If he uses the code that I put in my answer then the divs will resize as needed. I have changed the fiddle and replaced the "height" parameters with "min-height" in case he directly copies it.

Comment: The problem is that he's learning the wrong way and this is a learning community. Not only that but we are setting him up for failure. He will have to resize and readjust every item when he makes changes or add any content at all. I'm not talking about responsive. That is too much for hims to handle. But even fixed-width sites are responsive vertically. This is not. This is the same as drawing in a word document or Microsoft paint. You're hurting the guy

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant. I have changed my comment and explained why I set heights on the divs.

Comment: This is better, but the site is restricted to two columns. There is no flexibility horizontally (Not talking about responsive) I mean extending a div across the screen. Look, it's fine. This may seem like it's a simple fix, but I have seen this quick fixer uppers backfire too many times. Moving on.